# ¿Cómo usar Smart Terrain con más de un Image Target?

Tags: unity3d

Estoy usando vuforia con Unity3D y tengo un problema al usar Smart Terrain.

Tengo una escena con dos `Image Targets`, en uno de ellos he activado la opción de `Smart Terrain`. Cuando la aplicación detecta el otro `Image Target` muestra correctamente su objeto 3D que le he asociado, pero `Smart Terrain` lo trata también como si fuese un objeto real y lo sustituye por el `Prop Template` que tiene asignado.

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar el problema?